# How to Store Column Values in a Variable

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, csv

I am dealing with tab separated file that contains multiple columns.  Each column contain more than ~3000 records.

```
Column1     Column2  Column3     Column4
1000041     11657    GenNorm     albumin
1000043     24249    GenNorm     CaBP
1000043     29177    GenNorm     calcium-binding protein
1000045     2006     GenNorm     tropoelastin
```

**Problem:** Using Python, How to read the tab separated file and store each column (with its record) in a single variable.  Use "print" to print out a specific column(s)

**Preliminary code:** I used this code so far to read the tsv file

```
import csv
Dictionary1 = {}

with open("sample.txt", 'r') as samplefile:
        reader = csv.reader(samplefile, delimiter="\t")
```

Comment: The problem as written doesn't make sense. Given that 5-line input, what do you want the output to be?

Comment: I have edit the question ... Do not pay attention to the dots ...

Comment: Your edited question still doesn't show us what you want the output to be.

Comment: My objective is to assign the values of each column (i.e. Column1) to a variable (i.e. Variable1).  So later I would be able to compare the values of the assigned variable (Variable1) with other variable holding similar values.  

I hope this give you more perspective ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just asking how to "transpose" a CSV file from a sequence of rows to a sequence of columns.

In Python, you can always transpose any iterable of iterables by using the `zip` function:

```
with open("sample1.txt") as samplefile:
    reader = csv.reader(samplefile, delimiter="\t")
    columns = zip(*reader)
```

Now, if you want to print each column in order:

```
for column in columns:
    print(column)
```

Here, `columns` is an iterator of tuples. If you want some other format, like a dict mapping the column names to a list of values, you can transform it easily. For example:

```
columns = {column[0]: list(column[1:]) for column in columns}
```

Or, if you want to put them in four separate variables, you can just use normal tuple unpacking:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4 = columns
```

But there doesn't seem to be a very good reason to do that.

Comment: I just realized that my answer doesn't explain this, so: If you go with the last version, and you later want to correlate two columns with each other later (as your comments imply), that's another job for `zip`. For example, `zip(col1, col4)` gets you an iterable of pairs like `('100041', 'albumin')`, while `dict(zip(col4, col1))` gets you a mapping where you can look up `'albumin'` and get `'100041'`.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure the code in python but use this loop. Once you store everything into the dictionary then use this loop then use the function to call the index to print the method you can modify the function to suit what you want the key to be you can pass through a word to search etc

```
int mainCounter = 0;
int counter1 = 0;
string arrColumn1[3000];

int counter2 = 0;
string arrColumn1[3000];

int counter3 = 0;
string arrColumn1[3000];

int counter4 = 0;
string arrColumn1[3000];

for(int i = 0; i<dictionary.length; ++i){
      switch ( mainCounterounter )
      {
         case 0:
            arrColumn1[counter1] = dictionary[i];
            ++counter1;
            ++mainCounter;
            break;
         case 1:
            arrColumn2[counter2] = dictionary[i];
            ++counter2;
            ++mainCounter;
            break;
         case 2:
            arrColumn3[counter3] = dictionary[i];
            ++counter3;
            ++mainCounter;
            break;
         case 3:
            arrColumn4[counter4] = dictionary[i];
            ++counter4;
            mainCounter = 0;
            break;
      }
}
```

---

```
void printRecordFunction(int colToSearch, string findThis, string arr1[], string arr2[], string arr3[], string arr4[]){

int foundIndex=0;


if(colToSearch == 1){
      for(int i = 0; i<arr1.length; ++i){
           if(strcmp(arr1[i], findthis)==0){
                foundIndex = i;
                break;
           }
      }
}else if(colToSearch == 2){
      for(int i = 0; i<arr2.length; ++i){
           if(strcmp(arr2[i], findthis)==0){
                foundIndex = i;
                break;
           }
      }
}else if(colToSearch == 3){
      for(int i = 0; i<arr3.length; ++i){
           if(strcmp(arr3[i], findthis)==0){
                foundIndex = i;
                break;
           }
      }
}else if(colToSearch == 4){
      for(int i = 0; i<arr4.length; ++i){
           if(strcmp(arr4[i], findthis)==0){
                foundIndex = i;
                break;
           }
      }
}

count<<"Record: " << arr1[i] << " " << arr2[i] << " " << arr3[i] << " " << arr4[i] << endl;

}
```

Sorry this is all pretty hard code but I hope it gives you some idea and you can adjust it

Comment: This has nothing to do with python.